# T4 change output of "FileName.tt" to "FileName1.cs"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, t4

Microsoft documentation for T4 in VS2012 speaks:

> For example, if your Visual Studio project includes a template file
>   named MyTemplate.tt which contains the following directive:
>
> `<#@output extension=".cs"#>`
>
> then Visual Studio will generate a file named MyTemplate.cs

But in my project it changes `AssemblyInfo.tt` into `AssemblyInfo1.cs`.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Is there already an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file?

Comment: No, there is no one in solution and I have also checked harddrive

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942851/why-does-my-t4-template-append-a-number-to-the-file-name